# How to auto select other 2 in a slicer when I select one?

Tags: powerbi, slicers

I have a slicer has 4 options: closed, not resolved , open, new. Is there a way when I select open, then auto select not resolved, open and new. But still be able to select single not resolved or new.

I could only think about create 2 slicers filtering each other. Could this be done in one single slicer?

Comment: Create a hierarchy and use that for the slicer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use one slicer but still needs two columns to make it:

**1. Create a new column:**

```
Slicer = SWITCH(TRUE(),
```

[Column]="not resolved"||[Column]="new"||[Column]="open","open",
[Column])

[image]

Either in one slicer or in two slicers you always need this new column.

**2. Put these two columns into one slicer with new column [Slicer] in top and old column [Column] in bottom:**

[image]